# How to manipulate the 'value' in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, performance-testing

The Scenario is,

I recorded the task, which is,

Login, edit a field and save it with different name(but the original field remains),logout.

Here i need to manipulate the 'name' field, so i can get 100 or more copies of it, with unique names.

Is it possible in Selenium IDE?, if not , is there any open source tool available to do the same?

```
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/SurveyHome.aspx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvSurvey_ctl02</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsurname</td>
    <td>Survey 1</td> // This is the name of the survey.
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btncopysurok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btncopyok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

How to use the while loop in this code, i tried using but, the selenium ide is not recognising it.Can you plz help me with this..

Comment: What do you mean with "100 more copies"?

Comment: Thats for an example i put 100 or more copies.. But what i need is, to copy a survey(for instance) name it as "A" , then copy the same survey and name it as "B", repeat the process by changing only the name of it. The Result i'll have is i have the same survey with different names. is that makes sense?

Comment: You want to make several copies of same field with different names, if that is you want to do then Yes, you can do it in Selenium RC or Web Driver. Give more information about webapp.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking for, it sounds like you want to submit some sort of form 100 times with different names, is that correct? if so I would also suggest looking into WebDriver

Comment: Yes,i want to make several copies of same field with different names. But in selenium ide, we can change the name manually one by one and run the test, so we can create one copy for one test run. Is there any way to give a 'for' loop using javascript(or in anyways),in source code of selenium ide to do this process? or only way in selenium is to do it in selenium RC or Webdriver.

Comment: you want a genuine name in the name field or dummy name ?

Comment: dummy name will be okey. But for instance, Survey '1' to Survey '100',if we can cahnge only the numbers 1 to 100 to create, it will be fine.

Comment: In that case it can be done using a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You can use while loop for your purpose 

    <tr>
        <td>getEval</td>
        <td>index = 1;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>while</td>
        <td>index &lt; 10;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeEval</td>
        <td>index</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>survey ${value}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>getEval</td>
        <td>index++;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>endWhile</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    in the name text box field you give the value has survey ${value},
    now you can create any number of form with unique name by 
    using this while loop put your form inside this while loop.

    Try it

    Thank you.


<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/SurveyHome.aspx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index = 1;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>index &lt; 100;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>index</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>survey ${value}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvSurvey_ctl02</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsurname</td>
    <td>survey ${value}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btncopyok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index++;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>


try it.

thank you
```

Comment: Nikhil do look at the content body, i have put the code. plz help me out to manipulate the survey name.

Comment: vignesh try the above script since i dont get the interface i am not sure.think it will fine